# Compare files in one parent dir to those in another and copy missing files to 3rd dir

Tags: batch-file

I know there are probably tools out there that do what I am wanting to do, but I need this to be in batch. I am trying to get a batch file built so that I can have all files in the subfolders of one parent directory compared to the files in the subfolders of the second directory and then have all files missing from the second directory copied from the first parent directory to a third directory.

Take for example:

```
Parent dir 1= X:\Testing\Working (has arbitrary subdirs like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.)
Parent dir 2= D:\Files\Dump (has subdirs for year, month, and day)
Parent dir 3= X:\Testing\Processing (has the same arbitrary subdirs just as parent dir 1)
```

I want to have the batch look at the files in parent dir 1, compare them to the files in parent dir 2 only for the last 48 hours or so (since there are thousands of files in the "Dump" location), and have any files missing from parent dir 2 copied to parent dir 3.

What I am running into currently is that I can get a `fc` command working to compare the files in parent dir 1 to those in parent dir 2, but it compares the whole path in which it fails because X:\Testing\Working\1\testfile.txt does not exist in D:\Files\Dump\1\testfile.txt (it would be D:\Files\Dump\2016\6\9\testfile.txt). I tried a `forfiles` command, but could not get it working and have seen that it is slow so I stopped trying with that.

If I can just get something to take the first file and recursively compare it to all folders/files within 48 hours (or two days), then I can get the loop part working for the remaining files. I'm not really sure where to go with this as I am far from a batch master so any points in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

PS: Would it be any easier to have the batch create a list of files in Dir 1, compare them to a list of files in Dir 2, and then actually push the missing files to Dir 3?

EDIT: Well, I found part of my problem this whole time. Using the `dir /b /a-d` command with `/s` results in the entire path being included with the filename instead of just the file name. It works fine if I point the path to the correct folder for one file, but I need it to work with subfolders. Is there anyway to use `dir /b /a-d /s` and only get the file names? Would it need another `for` command?

Comment: Can your batch start with `powershell.exe -C ...`  ?

Comment: I don't see why it couldn't. The reason for batch is that it just has to run on a client machine without any other applications or features installed on it. I, however, am not familiar with powershell whatsoever.

Comment: It's worth learning. Your client machine will almost certainly have powershell installed by default (Win7+), and it's a *much* better language than batch (as are most languages).

Comment: Where would be a good place to start? Or do you have some code that would fit my request that I could dissect?